# Rearrange data in a single column into multiple columns with Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, yaml, powerquery

I have data that is a function of two parameters that is imported from a .yaml file. The first column contains one of the parameters, the second column contains the data grouped by the second parameter which is included at the beginning of each group. I want to transform this data into a 2-dimensional table in Excel for graphing multiple parameterized lines.

The .yaml file looks like this.  It will always be fixed length:

```
A:
  a: 1
  b: 2
  c: 3
B:
  a: 4
  b: 5
  c: 6
```

The imported data looks like this in Power Query (after importing as non-delimited text and minor manipulation in Excel Power Query):

```
Column1  |  Column2
-------------------
  null   |    A
   a     |    1
   b     |    2
   c     |    3
  null   |    B
   a     |    4
   b     |    5
   c     |    6
```

I'd like to transform it to this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
---------------------------
 null   |    A    |   B
  a     |    1    |   4
  b     |    2    |   5
  c     |    3    |   6
```

I don't need a complete solution, just a yes or no for whether it can be done, and the key concepts of the solution if it can be done. I'll fill in the details for any solutions as I have time to work through them (since this is what Stack Exchange wants to see, detailed solutions).

Comment: If it's fixed size like in your sample, you can make QueryA and QueryB with some mix of [`Table.FirstN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-firstn), [`Table.LastN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-lastn), [`Table.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-range), and [`Table.Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-skip).  Then you can merge (UI label for joining) with [`Table.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-join), based on a join column of your [Column1].

Comment: Thanks! I figured out another way that I will add here, but will try your solution too.

Comment: Group the rows by Column1. Use `Table.Column` to convert to a `List`. Expand the list with a delimiter separation.  Split the expanded list to the new columns.  Delete the unneeded columns.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at this approach too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I solved this after a search. Note that this is not ideal because it only works for a fixed size file. This could be parameterized, but there is likely a way to make it work for a variable sized file without needing the sizes entered as parameters. Also, I scrambled the data a bit to more closely resemble the actual problem.

This is a simplified rendition of my .yaml file. I read this in as text without delimiters.

```
 A:
   a: 2
   b: 1
   c: 6
 B:
   a: 5
   b: 4
   c: 3
```

By using the Find & Replace (I used four steps)

```
,A
a,2
b,1
c,6
,B
a,5
b,4
c,3
```

Split Column by Delimiter (a comma here)

```
Column1  |  Column2
-------------------
  null   |    A
   a     |    2
   b     |    1
   c     |    6
  null   |    B
   a     |    5
   b     |    4
   c     |    3
```

Added Index and Inserted Modulo 4 column(operates on Column3 to create Column4)

```
Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3  |  Column4
-------------------------------------------
  null   |    A      |     0     |    0
   a     |    2      |     1     |    1
   b     |    1      |     2     |    2
   c     |    6      |     3     |    3
  null   |    B      |     4     |    0
   a     |    5      |     5     |    1
   b     |    4      |     6     |    2
   c     |    3      |     7     |    3
```

Sorted Rows by Column4, added another index, and added a modulo 2 column.

```
Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3  |  Column4  |  Column5  |  Column6
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  null   |    A      |     0     |     0     |     0     |    0
  null   |    B      |     4     |     0     |     1     |    1
   a     |    2      |     1     |     1     |     2     |    0
   a     |    5      |     5     |     1     |     3     |    1
   b     |    1      |     2     |     2     |     4     |    0
   b     |    4      |     6     |     2     |     5     |    1
   c     |    6      |     3     |     3     |     6     |    0
   c     |    3      |     7     |     3     |     7     |    1
```

Sort on Column6 to get groupings of rows that will go into a single column, with the column number in Column6

```
Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3  |  Column4  |  Column5  |  Column6
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  null   |    A      |     0     |     0     |     0     |    0
   a     |    2      |     1     |     1     |     2     |    0
   b     |    1      |     2     |     2     |     4     |    0
   c     |    6      |     3     |     3     |     6     |    0
  null   |    B      |     4     |     0     |     1     |    1
   a     |    5      |     5     |     1     |     3     |    1
   b     |    4      |     6     |     2     |     5     |    1
   c     |    3      |     7     |     3     |     7     |    1
```

Pivot on Column6 with Values coming from Column2

```
Column1  |  Column3  |  Column4  |  Column5  |    0    |    1
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  null   |     0     |     0     |     0     |    A    |   null
  null   |     4     |     0     |     1     |   null  |    B
   a     |     1     |     1     |     2     |    2    |   null
   a     |     5     |     1     |     3     |   null  |    5
   b     |     2     |     2     |     4     |    1    |   null
   b     |     6     |     2     |     5     |   null  |    4
   c     |     3     |     3     |     6     |    6    |   null   
   c     |     7     |     3     |     7     |   null  |    3
```

Fill up (Column) 1

```
Column1  |  Column3  |  Column4  |  Column5  |    0    |    1
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  null   |     0     |     0     |     0     |    A    |    B
  null   |     4     |     0     |     1     |   null  |    B
   a     |     1     |     1     |     2     |    2    |    5
   a     |     5     |     1     |     3     |   null  |    5
   b     |     2     |     2     |     4     |    1    |    4
   b     |     6     |     2     |     5     |   null  |    4
   c     |     3     |     3     |     6     |    6    |    3   
   c     |     7     |     3     |     7     |   null  |    3
```

Filter (Column) 0 on null and remove Column3, Column4, and Column5 to get the final result

```
Column1  |    0    |    1
-----------------------------
  null   |    A    |    B
   a     |    2    |    5
   b     |    1    |    4
   c     |    6    |    3
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this approach should work, but I don't know how to do the third step.

```
Column1  |  Column2
-------------------
  null   |    A
   a     |    2
   b     |    1
   c     |    6
  null   |    B
   a     |    5
   b     |    4
   c     |    3
```

Add conditional Column3 based off of Column1

```
Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3
-------------------------------
  null   |    A      |    0
   a     |    2      |   null
   b     |    1      |   null
   c     |    6      |   null
  null   |    B      |    0
   a     |    5      |   null
   b     |    4      |   null
   c     |    3      |   null
```

Here is the step I do not know how to do! In this simple example, there is only one change.

```
Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3
-------------------------------
  null   |    A      |    0
   a     |    2      |   null
   b     |    1      |   null
   c     |    6      |   null
  null   |    B      |    1
   a     |    5      |   null
   b     |    4      |   null
   c     |    3      |   null
```

Fill Column3 down

```
Column1  |  Column2  |  Column3
-------------------------------
  null   |    A      |    0
   a     |    2      |    0
   b     |    1      |    0
   c     |    6      |    0
  null   |    B      |    1
   a     |    5      |    1
   b     |    4      |    1
   c     |    3      |    1
```

Pivot

```
Column1  |    0      |    1
-------------------------------
  null   |    A      |   null
  null   |   null    |    B
   a     |    2      |   null
   a     |   null    |    5
   b     |    1      |   null
   b     |   null    |    4
   c     |    6      |   null
   c     |   null    |    3
```

Fill Upward on (Column) 1, Filter null on (Column) 0

```
Column1  |    0      |    1
-------------------------------
  null   |    A      |    B
   a     |    2      |    5
   b     |    1      |    4
   c     |    6      |    3
```